# First job in second stage contains previous job's state in GitLab

Tags: docker, gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have run across an issue where the first job in my test stage receives the entire state of my previous build job when I don't expect it too. I've simplified the problem down as much as possible in order to still reproduce the issue. Essentially, build runs and checks out my repo. ls -al prints the working directory out which contains my checked out repo. test-one runs, skips the git checkout, and prints the working directory which contains the git checkout from the previous build job. test-two runs, skips the git checkout, and prints the working directory which contains an empty directory as expected.

My questions are, did I configure my .gitlab-ci.yml file incorrectly, do my expectations lack understanding of how GitLab should work, is GitLab or the runner improperly configured, or is this a bug?

Things to note:

- I am using GitLab version: 12.6.4-ee
- I am NOT the GitLab administrator
- The jobs do not depend on each other and the scripts simply print the current working directory.
- My docker image is simply a clean base image of a Linux distro with nothing but common Linux commands installed.
- linux-runner is a GitLab-runner running as a service on my Linux server.
- I disable git from checking out my repo in the test jobs in order to see that the checkout from the build job is present in test-one.

Below is my .gitlab-ci.yml file simplified:

```
image: $DOCKER_REGISTRY/my-image:latest

build:
    stage: build
    tags:
        - linux-runner
    script:
        - ls -al

test-one:
    stage: test
    tags:
        - linux-runner
    variables:
        GIT_STRATEGY: none
    script:
        - ls -al

 test-two:
    stage: test
    tags:
        - linux-runner
    variables:
        GIT_STRATEGY: none
    script:
        - ls -al
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be caused by my usage of GIT_STRATEGY: none. By removing the variables I began to receive expected behavior once again.

Answer (score 0):

image: $DOCKER_REGISTRY/my-image:latest

```
stages: # <-- add them all
  - build
  - test1
  - test2

build:
    stage: build
    tags:
        - linux-runner
    script:
        - ls -al

test-one:
    stage: test1 # <-- change this
    tags:
        - linux-runner
    variables:
        GIT_STRATEGY: none
    script:
        - ls -al

 test-two:
    stage: test2 # <-- change this
    tags:
        - linux-runner
    variables:
        GIT_STRATEGY: none
    script:
        - ls -al
```

On your case `test-one` & `test-two` share the same "kind of" environment.

By setting up two different stages, they'll have their own environment

Comment: This is a simplified file but I need both test stages to occur within the same stage as there are dependent stages later on. stackoverflow removed my solution but by removing `GIT_STRATEGY: none` my problem went away.